# Equivalent Grids

Tags: logic-grid

The two grids below are essentially equivalent. A specific color belongs to a specific catagory (four solid colors). Exception is the center box with 2 colors. Should be easy to fill out all the boxes with "?"
[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer**

Green:

> **An overlined V**. LI is Roman for 51. Numbers greater than 3,999 can be represented with Roman numerals with an overbar, which means the digit value is multiplied with 1,000.

White:

> **18:25**. The white-and-red image on the left is the flag of Poland; the red-and-white image on the right is the flag of Indonesia. 13:25 is the time in Poland (CEST). Indonesia spans across three time zones, but when it's 13:25 in Warsaw, it's 18:25 in Jakarta.

Yellow:

> Approximately **1.222**. An angle of 940° (which really is 220°) corresponds to 16.4 radians. 70° correpsond to 1.222 radians.

Comment: The planets are Jupiter -> Mars and the Moon -> Earth. Tried seeing if the numbers related to distance or size but neither give anything useful.

Comment: Apologies n_palum and everybody, I calculated for another moon. Now corrected

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

> The green ? is probably MMMMM or the fancy V that equals 5000 in roman numerals. Because LI equals 51.